# Refreshing a Partial with Ajax in Rails 3 with Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I have a partial that has a container that holds a bunch of items. If I add an item via ajax, I want to reflect that in this container without refreshing the page. I am having an issue finding a jquery/ajax way to refresh that one partial on the page. I am sure there is an easy way I am just missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.js.erb**

```
$('#container_id').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "partial", :formats => [:html])) %>');
```

---

**Full example:**

```
# CommentsController

def refresh_comments
  @comments = Comment.last_in(10.second) # fetch collection
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { } # by default renders views/comments/refresh_comments.html.erb as template
    format.js { } # by default renders views/comments/refresh_comments.js.erb as template
  end
end

# views/comments/refresh_comments.js.erb

$('#post_comments').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "comments_thread", :formats => [:html])) %>');

# * where: "post_comments" - is a DOM id of container.
#          "comments_thread" - name of partial. :formats => [:html] says that you render _comments.html.erb

# Look JQuery API for details.
```

Comment: This will call the server and refresh the partial?

Comment: Nope, this will be fired by the controller when you call your action via ajax, and then put something like `respond_to do |format| format :js end`

Comment: I'm having an issue getting it operating. I'm getting the error: javascript.js:1 Error: NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fed77861610>:0x007fed78e3d7e0>
  (in ****)

Comment: no, this code is for only js.erb templates (ajax requests). You can not access server's features within Javascript runtime. Only via Ajax.